# can't install libcups2-dev

Tags: linux-mint, drivers

> uname inf: Linux N551JB 4.11.0-999-lowlatency #201704042201 SMP PREEMPT

I wanted to install drivers for my hp printer, but I got problem with libcups2-dev package. That's what installing program said:

> command: sh hplip-3.17.4.run
>
> error: Package install command failed with error code 100

I tried to install it from Synaptic Package Manager, but it refused and gave an error:

> Depends: libcups2 (=2.1.3-4) but 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.2 is to be installed

Do anyone know how to solve this problem?

Output from command: apt-cache policy libcups2-dev libcups2

`libcups2-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.1.3-4
  Version table:
     2.1.3-4 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
libcups2:
  Installed: 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.2
  Candidate: 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.2
  Version table:
 *** 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.2 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.1.3-4 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages`

```
apt-get install libcups2

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libcups2 is already the newest version (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.2).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  account-plugin-tools accountsservice-ubuntu-schemas android-tools-adb
  android-tools-fastboot antlr3 apparmor-easyprof-ubuntu autopilot-qt4
  autopilot-qt5 bnd click click-apparmor click-dev click-doc
  click-reviewers-tools cmake-extras devscripts fbset gdb-multiarch
  gir1.2-click-0.4 gir1.2-gee-0.8 gir1.2-ubuntu-app-launch-2
  gsettings-ubuntu-schemas i965-va-driver:i386 java-wrappers javahelp2
  junit4-doc libantlr3-runtime-java libatinject-jsr330-api-java
  libatk-bridge2.0-0:i386 libatspi2.0-0:i386 libautopilot-qt
  libbeansbinding-java libbindex-java libboost-dev
  libboost-filesystem1.58.0:i386 libboost-python1.58.0 libboost-regex1.58.0
  libboost-serialization1.58.0 libboost-system1.58.0:i386 libboost1.58-dev
  libbotan-1.10-1 libbsh-java libbytelist-java libcapnp-0.5.3 libcdi-api-java
  libclick-0.4-0 libcolord2:i386 libcommons-io-java libcommons-lang-java
  libdbus-cpp5 libeclipselink-java libegl1-mesa:i386 libepoxy0:i386
  libfelix-framework-java libfelix-main-java libfreemarker-java libgbm1:i386
  libgeonames0 libgeronimo-interceptor-3.0-spec-java
  libgeronimo-j2ee-connector-1.5-spec-java libgeronimo-jms-1.1-spec-java
  libgeronimo-validation-1.0-spec-java libgflags2v5 libgoogle-glog0v5
  libgsettings-qt1 libgtk-3-0:i386 libhtml5parser-java libhttpclient-java
  libhttpcore-java libhud2 libicu-dev libicu4j-4.4-java libini4j-java
  libjansson4 libjavaewah-java libjcodings-java libjcommander-java
  libjemmy2-java libjgit-java libjna-java libjna-jni libjna-platform-java
  libjnlp-servlet-java libjoda-time-java libjpa-2.1-spec-java libjs-sphinxdoc
  libjsch-agent-proxy-java libjson-glib-1.0-0:i386 libjson-simple-java
  libjsr311-api-java libjvyamlb-java libjzlib-java libkeybinder0 libleveldb1v5
  liblttng-ust-ctl2 liblttng-ust0 liblucene3-java libmail-java
  libmirclient9:i386 libmircommon5:i386 libmirprotobuf3:i386 libmysql-java
  libnb-absolutelayout-java libnb-apisupport3-java libnb-ide14-java
  libnb-java5-java libnb-javaparser-java libnb-org-openide-modules-java
  libnb-org-openide-util-java libnb-org-openide-util-lookup-java
  libnb-platform-devel-java libnb-platform18-java libnet-cpp2
  libonline-accounts-client1 libpay2 libpostgresql-jdbc-java libprocess-cpp3
  libproperties-cpp-dev libprotobuf-lite9v5:i386 libqbscore1
  libqbsqtprofilesetup1 libqdjango-db0 libqgsttools-p1 libqmenumodel0
  libqt5designercomponents5 libqt5multimedia5-plugins libqt5multimediaquick-p5
  libqt5multimediawidgets5 libqt5organizer5 libqt5xmlpatterns5
  librest-0.7-0:i386 libscope-harness3 libsequence-library-java
  libservlet2.5-java libsimple-validation-java libslf4j-java libsqljet-java
  libstringtemplate4-java libsvn-java libsvnclientadapter-java libsvnkit-java
  libswing-layout-java libswingx-java libthumbnailer-qt1.0
  libtrilead-ssh2-java libtrust-store2 libubuntu-app-launch2
  libubuntu-location-service3 libubuntu-platform-hardware-api3
  libubuntugestures5 libubuntuoneauth-2.0-0 libubuntutoolkit5
  libunity-action-qt1 libunity-api-dev libunity-api0 libunity-scopes-dev
  libunity-scopes1.0 liburcu4 liburl-dispatcher1 libusermetricsoutput1
  libva-drm1:i386 libva-x11-1:i386 libva1:i386 libvdpau1 libvdpau1:i386
  libwayland-client0:i386 libwayland-cursor0:i386 libwayland-egl1-mesa:i386
  libwayland-server0:i386 libwine-development libws-commons-util-java
  libxcb-xfixes0:i386 libxerces2-java libxkbcommon0:i386
  libxml-commons-external-java libxnvctrl0 libxpathselect1.4v5 libzmqpp3
  lynx-common mesa-vdpau-drivers:i386 ocl-icd-libopencl1
  ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 pay-service pay-ui phablet-tools python-autopilot
  python-contextlib2 python-decorator python-evdev python-extras
  python-fixtures python-funcsigs python-junitxml python-keybinder
  python-linecache2 python-mimeparse python-mock python-pbr python-psutil
  python-pyexiv2 python-subunit python-testscenarios python-testtools
  python-traceback2 python-unittest2 python3-apparmor-click python3-autopilot
  python3-click-package python3-dateutil python3-decorator python3-extras
  python3-fixtures python3-junitxml python3-linecache2 python3-magic
  python3-mimeparse python3-pbr python3-psutil python3-scope-harness
  python3-simplejson python3-subunit python3-testscenarios python3-testtools
  python3-traceback2 python3-tz python3-unittest2
  qml-module-qt-labs-folderlistmodel qml-module-qt-labs-settings
  qml-module-qtfeedback qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects qml-module-qtmultimedia
  qml-module-qtquick-xmllistmodel qml-module-qttest
  qml-module-ubuntu-components qml-module-ubuntu-layouts
  qml-module-ubuntu-onlineaccounts qml-module-ubuntu-onlineaccounts-client
  qml-module-ubuntu-performancemetrics qml-module-ubuntu-test
  qml-module-ubuntu-thumbnailer0.1 qml-module-ubuntu-web qtcreator-data
  qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu-common qtdeclarative5-accounts-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-controls-plugin qtdeclarative5-gsettings1.0
  qtdeclarative5-online-accounts-client0.1 qtdeclarative5-qtquick2-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-settings-components
  qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-thumbnailer0.1 qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-web-plugin qtdeclarative5-unity-action-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-unity-notifications-plugin qttestability-autopilot schroot
  schroot-common screen-resolution-extra sqlite3 suru-icon-theme testng
  thumbnailer-service ubuntu-mobile-icons ubuntu-push-client
  ubuntu-sdk-qmake-extras ubuntu-ui-toolkit-doc ubuntu-ui-toolkit-examples
  ubuntu-ui-toolkit-theme ubuntu-ui-toolkit-tools ubuntuone-client-data
  ubuntuone-credentials-common unity-asset-pool unity-plugin-scopes
  unity-schemas unity-scope-tool unity-webapps-qml unity8-common
  unity8-fake-env unity8-private url-dispatcher usermetricsservice
  va-driver-all:i386 vdpau-driver-all:i386 vdpau-va-driver:i386
  webapp-container webbrowser-app
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
```

Comment: This is a common error often indicating version mismatches. Please paste the output of `apt-cache policy libcups2-dev libcups2` into the question, not as a comment, please.

Comment: (Sigh.) Did you read the part about not putting it in a comment? Put the command and the output in the question, please.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Done

Comment: Ok. Try `apt-get install libcups2`. Paste the output in the question, please. Also, you wrote "that's what installing program said:" Please include the complete commands that you executed.

Comment: @FaheemMitha finished

Comment: Run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` then `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: @GAD3R Second command give an error. The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcups2-dev : Depends: libcups2 (= 2.1.3-4) but 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.2 is to be installed

Comment: Ok, it's a downgrade. Do `apt-get install libcups2=2.1.3-4` instead, and as before paste the command and the output in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `libcups2` package

```
sudo apt-get remove libcups2
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Then reinstall it as follows:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cups/libcups2_2.1.3-4ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libcups2_2.1.3-4ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
```